# Capturing dns requests

Tags: c++

How it is possible to capture dns requests, just requests, I don't need anything else. What library (c++) is best for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html) is the most popular and best-supported network packet capture library I know; it supports easy query strings like `udp port 53`.